# Are two states equivalent in a DFA if on the same input the states transition to each other?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Suppose you have three states in an DFA $q_{1}$, $q_{2}$ and $q_{3}$, all non-accepting. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two symbols, such that:

$\delta(q_{1},a)=q_{2}\\ \delta(q_{2},a)=q_{1}$

and

$\delta(q_{1},b)=q_{3}\\ \delta(q_{2},b)=q_{3}$

Are the states $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ considered equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  If there is another symbol in the alphabet, $c$, such that $q_1$ transitions to $q_4$ on $c$ but $q_2$ transitions to $q_5$ then they are clearly not equivalent.

Comment: Understood. But in case $\sum = {a,b}$, they are equivalent?

Comment: Very good point, but with $q4$ and $q5$ being equivalent it would mean that there are two superflous states, so it is still unknown.

Answer (score 3):

> "We say that states $p$ and $q$ are *equivalent* if:
>
> - For all input strings $w$, $\hat{\delta}(p,w)$ is an accepting state if and only if $\hat{\delta}(q,w)$ is an accepting state."
>
> (John E. Hopcroft, Rajeev Motwani, and Jeffrey D. Ullman. 2001. Introduction to automata theory, languages, and computation, 2nd edition.)

So if the automaton doesn't accept any strings, there cannot be a string that *distinguishes* the two states, and therefore there cannot be an equivalence between two states.

Comment: If we play with the thought of the DFA having a *start state*, let's say $q_1$ or $q_2$ and $q_3$ would be an accepting state. Then yes, then it would be fair to say that $q_1$ and $q_2$ are equivalent over $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$.

Comment: Both are in nonaccepting state, so according to quote these states are equivalent, but this depends also on transition function, so this is not a full story.

Answer (score 2):

Please read about [DFA minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization), in your case $q_1$ and $q_2$ are nondistinguishable, both are nonaccepting states. The transition for $b$ is the same, for $a$ they alternate between each other, so you can say that $q_1$ and $q_2$ are equivalent.

Comment: How do you define distinguishable in this context?

Comment: @GabrielTigerström [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/notemindfa.pdf) I follow this definitions. Nitpick would be to call them 2-nondistinguishable (and 1-equivalent) and show that these are the same using e.g. Moore algorithm and then call them equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If $q_1, q_2, q_3$ are the only three states in a DFA and all three are non-accepting then the language of the DFA is empty and so $q_1, q_2, q_3$ are all equivalent. If there are other states in the DFA as well, then two states can only be equivalent if both lead to a non-accepting state or if both lead to an accepting state for any given string. You are only checking for one symbol, i.e. string of length 1, which is not enough to prove equivalence.